# Is f(x) = x continuous using this false definition?

Tags: continuity

Let A ⊂ R. Function f : A → R is continuous in point a ∈ A, if there exists ε > 0, so that with every δ > 0

|f(x) − f(a)| < ε, when x ∈ A and |x − a| < δ.

Is function f : R → R, f(x) = x for all x ∈ R, continuous in point 0 when using this false definition?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I think it's not, but I have only gotten in to a solution that if we choose δ = 2ε, we can get |x| < δ = 2ε. I think it doesn't still proof anything as it doesn't say |x| > ε.

Comment: Your are on the right way. The false definition requires that $|x| = |f(x)-f(0)| < \epsilon$ must be true for *all* $x$ with $|x| < \delta=2\epsilon$. Maybe you can find one $x$ that fulfills the second condition but not the first?

Comment: So can I say that if |x| < ε must be true for all x with |x| < 2ε, there is a clear contratiction as this second condition allows for example |x| = 3ε/2 > ε.

Comment: Exactly. One counterexample is enough.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very nuch.